# elasticsearch - how to copy data to another cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get an elasticsearch index to a file and then insert that data to another cluster?
I want to move data from one cluster to another but I can't connect them directly.

Comment: Is the elasticsearch version the same on both cluster?

Comment: Cool, how about the layout: how many nodes? Same number of nodes on both clusters?

Comment: On the current cluster I have 7 data nodes and one without data only for dispatching with 3 shards and 1 replica. And I want to move all data to another cluster with 4 nodes and 1 dispacher with 4 shards and 1 replica.

Comment: Ok, was asking to understand whether you need to reindex data or you can use the existing index. If you want to have a different number of primary shards you definitely need to, unfortunately. Did you index data from a database? Or is elasticsearch your data storage too?

Comment: I use elasticsearch for data storage too.

Comment: I'm still searching for a solution.

Comment: Elasticsearch 1.0 has a snapshot API that you can use. Alternatively, see [this python script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24911018/509706).

Answer (score 2):

If you no need to keep _id the same and only important bit is _source you may use logstash with config:

```
input { //from one cluster } output { //to another cluster }
```

here is more info: http://www.logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/

Yes it's method is weird, but I tried it for instant data transfer between clusters index by index and it is working as a charm (of course if you no need to keep _id generated by elasticsearch)

Answer (score 1):

There is script which will help you to backup and restore indices from one cluster to another. i didn't tested this but may be it will fix your needs.
check this [Backup and restore an Elastic search index](https://github.com/clintongormley/ElasticSearch.pm)

And you can also use perl script to copy index from one cluster to another (or the same cluster).

check this link [clintongormley/ElasticSearch.pm](https://github.com/clintongormley/ElasticSearch.pm)

Comment: links are dead. Please update links or delete answer.

Comment: @colidyre check this link but its old and i think they are strongly recommand to use official python api. https://github.com/eriky/ESClient. check this also my forked version has copy script https://github.com/kirubar/ESClient

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried my hands around this and there are a couple of approaches that can help you.

1. Use Elasticsearch's [Snapshot and Restore APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/snapshot-restore-apis.html).
   You can [take a snapshot](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/create-snapshot-api.html) at the source cluster and [use that snapshot to restore](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/restore-snapshot-api.html) data to your destination cluster.
2. If your setup allows installing external packages, you can use [Elasticdump](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticdump) as well.

HTH!