# Migrating dashboards from Kibana 4 to Kibana 5

Tags: kibana, kibana-4, kibana-5

I'm trying to migrate my old dashboards fron kibana 4.1.2 to kibana 5.0.0. , but haven't been able to successfully do it.
I took an export of my searches, visualisations and dashboards from the older version and imported it to the newer version. But, the visualisations said they didn't find they couldn't locate index-pattern.

`Saved Objects: Could not locate that index-pattern (id: [logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD)`

`Error: Could not locate that index-pattern (id: [logstash-]YYYY.MM.DD)
    at updateFromElasticSearch (http://development-log-server*****.com:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=14438:25:9602)
    at http://development-log-server*****.com:5601/bundles/kibana.bundle.js?v=14438:25:13725
    at processQueue (http://development-log-server*****.com:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=14438:38:23621)
    at http://development-log-server*****.com:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=14438:38:23888
    at Scope.$eval (http://development-log-server*****.com:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=14438:39:4619)
    at Scope.$digest (http://development-log-server*****.com:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=14438:39:2359)
    at Scope.$apply (http://development-log-server*****.com:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=14438:39:5037)
    at done (http://development-log-server*****.com:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=14438:37:25027)
    at completeRequest (http://development-log-server*****.com:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=14438:37:28702)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onload (http://development-log-server*****.com:5601/bundles/commons.bundle.js?v=14438:37:29634)`

I would really appreciate if someone could steer me in the right direction and even more grateful if someone could point me to a tool to do the migration.

And please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks,
Ashutosh Singh

Comment: Firstly, you need to _migrate_ indices to `ES 5.0` using **reindex api**. Then add all indices in Kibana 5 in _index-patterns_ section. Then import visualizations and dashboards into kibana-5. It worth reading doc: [migration-plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/breaking-changes-5.0.html#migration-plugin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you could do that in a simple manner, considering a downtime. Maybe you could give it a try by using [elasticdump](http://air.ghost.io/kibana-4-export-and-import-visualizations-and-dashboards/). Moving the index data to another instance could be a pain but then you could use the `python elasticsearch library` ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048179/location-of-custom-kibana-dashboards-in-elasticsearch)).

Or else you could store it as Objects and then import them back. Storing it as a `JSON`, was added back in `Kibana 4.1`. Hope [this](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-save-dashboard-as-json-file/24561/10) helps.

A clear guide to [managing kibana visualizations and dashboards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/managing-saved-objects.html#managing-saved-objects).

Comment: thanks @Kulasangar. Your suggestion helped and I was able to export the dashboards and visualizations. I faced some problems while initialising those dashborads and visualizations though. It gace me the same error as in my original post. I don't understand why the same error occured. The name of kibana index has been the same for both the kibana instance i.e. the default index _"logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"_. Any thoughts

Comment: One more thing. My old elasticsearch is on version 1.7.3 and the new one is on version 5.0.0. So, do I need to reindex my elasticsearch instance?