# kibana running on docker: how to save dashboard?

Tags: docker, kibana

I am running kibana 5.2.1 from docker. I am using this image: `FROM docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:5.2.1`

The problem is if I remove the container the work done on kibana will be lost.
How can I save kibana dashboard on docker instance?

can I use docker volume? if yes which folder in the container store kibana data so I can map it to a local folder.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Location of custom Kibana dashboards in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048179/location-of-custom-kibana-dashboards-in-elasticsearch)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Based on this question, it looks like it saves into elasticsearch, so you don't need to mount a shared volume.

[Location of custom Kibana dashboards in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048179/location-of-custom-kibana-dashboards-in-elasticsearch)