# Ship readymade dashboards in kibana docker image and rpm

Tags: kibana, dashboard, docker-image

I have a twofold question:

- How to ship in built reports and dashboards in `kibana` docker image and rpm ?

My requirement is that when any user installs `kibana` using a docker image or rpm and starts running it in browser, he/she sees some already made dashboards in it before creating anyone themselves.

- How can I ship ready-made dashboards with the docker image or rpm?

Comment: Apparently users can create dashboards? This means that they are stored somewhere, probably some database. So either provide a database including default dashboards, or create/store default dashboards when none are found.

Answer (score 0):

The reports/dashboards are stored in Elastic Search itself.
See ->
[Location of custom Kibana dashboards in ElasticSearch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22048179/2092817)

If there is single instance of ES, then that will shared by different users.

Comment: My question is around docker image of the kibana. What you are saying is that dashboards are saved in ES. So in the docker compose file we will be having ES and Kibana as two services. So how the dashboards will be preserved in the docker file of ES? can you please clarify?

Comment: Can you share the docker-compose file you are using? 
So, you want to have your custom dashboards when you do docker-compose up?

Comment: Yes exactly.. thats the requirement. I researched on this but did not find anything useful. I just wanted to figure out that whether there is any way to do it or not. I have not written the docker file yet.